# Irreducible Representations of Nilpotent Lie algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

By Lie's theorem all irreducible representations of a solvable Lie algebra over $\mathbb C$ are one dimensional. What are all irreducible representations of a nilpotent Lie algebra ?

Comment: Every nilpotent Lie algebra is solvable; is there something more specific that you need about their representations?